# Nomadic Labs indexer bootstrap fails with statement timeout

Tags: snapshots, indexer, database

I restored the database of the Nomadic Labs indexer using a snapshot called "v10.2.0.20220817.sql", then updated the schema to v10.2.1 with `make db-schema-all-default | psql -p 5433 --username=user --dbname=db` and then tried to bootstrap the indexer with the Docker image using:

```
docker run -it --rm --net=host registry.gitlab.com/nomadic-labs/tezos-indexer/tezos-indexer:v10.2.1 --verbose --db=postgresql://user:user@localhost:5433/db --tezos-url=[local node url]
```

The error I get, after some apparently successful insertions in the database is the following:

```
> event=insert block_level=2630354 block=BLn8VrkdhDxc type=contract_balance address=tz1cpaeGrCgrWcYm5kAWbestAV8Pr22aARod balance=356.294474
Database error: Request to <postgresql://user:_@localhost:5433/db> failed: ERROR:  canceling statement due to statement timeout
CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function b.get_for_copy(bigint,integer,bigint,bigint) line 15 at RETURN QUERY
SQL statement "INSERT INTO C.bigmap
 (id, "key", key_hash, "key_type", "value", value_type, block_level, sender_id, receiver_id, i,                    operation_id, implicit_operations_results_id, kind, annots, strings, uri, contracts, metadata, operation_hash_id) --
SELECT
 yid, r."key", r.key_hash, r."key_type", r."value", r.value_type, xblock_level, xsender, xreceiver,
 xi, opaid, iorid, coalesce((select -1 where kind < 1), 3), r.annots, r.strings, r.uri, r.contracts, r.metadata, ophid
FROM B.get_for_copy (xid, xblock_level, ophid, xi) r
ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING"
PL/pgSQL function b.copy(bigint,bigint,integer,bigint,bigint,bigint,bigint,integer,bigint) line 5 at SQL statement
 Query: "select B.copy($1,$2,$3,$4,$5,$6,$7,$8,$9)".
```

I actually had this issue even before restoring the snapshot, and trying to start afresh does not fix it. I checked that the statement timeout is not set by default:

```
db=> show statement_timeout;
 statement_timeout 
-------------------
 0
(1 row)

db=> SELECT current_setting('statement_timeout');
 current_setting 
-----------------
 0
(1 row)
```

Could it be that the indexer is setting its own timeout for its session? If so, how can I change it?

(Note that `user` and `db` are just placeholders in the fragments above.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a default value for the DB timeout, as you may read from the README or from --help:

```
       --timeout=VAL (absent=60s)
           Specify DB query timeout. If no unit is given, the integer is
           considered a number of milliseconds. 0 means no timeout. Examples:
           10s, 1234ms, 42m. Cf. Postgres' documentation for more
           information. This can be very useful if your instance gets stuck
           sometimes and you'd like it to crash so you can automatically
           restart it. (Since v9.7.9)
```

If your hardware is not fast enough, it'll be indeed necessary to increase the 60s timeout value.

If ever you're not interested in big maps anyways, let me know: it's not very complicated to deactivate recording big maps in the DB.